# Clear iOS Safari icon cache?

Tags: ios, safari, icon, mobile-safari

Is there a way to clear the favicon/apple-touch-icon cache for mobile Safari? The "delete all website data" button in settings doesn't do it.

(Safari appears to cache website icons aggressively for the "Add to Bookmarks"/"Add to Favorites" functions, but not for "Add to Home Screen". I'm interested in the former.)

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to refresh it by loading ./apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png, but I only had apple-touch-icon.png in my main folder and had deleted the outdated precomposed one, so I believe you have to go to the original address that was stored in iOS Safari's cache.

It could be any of the following addresses, which are recommended by [Apple Documentation on Web Applications](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html):

- apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png
- apple-touch-icon.png
- touch-icon-ipad-retina.png
- touch-icon-ipad.png
- touch-icon-iphone.png

And don't forget to compress your PNG to save bandwidth!